# What is the difference between these two solutions on learnyounode 9#?

Tags: javascript

Could someone please explain what is the difference between these two solutions below? In my opinion logic of both solutions is the same. But the first solution is correct and second is not. I know that it's something to do with index of array but can't get the logic behind it.

Correct:

```
const http = require('http');
const bl  = require('bl');
let count = 0;
const message = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let currentIndex = i
    http.get(process.argv[2+i], (res) => {
    res.pipe(bl((err,data) => {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err)
        }
        message[currentIndex] = data.toString()
        count++

        if(count === 3) {
            for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                console.log(message[i])
            }
        }
    }))
  })
}
```

Fail:

```
const http = require('http');
const bl  = require('bl')
let count = 0;
const message = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    http.get(process.argv[2+i], (res) => {
    res.pipe(bl((err,data) => {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err)
        }
        message[count] = data.toString()
        count++

        if(count === 3) {
            for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                console.log(message[i])
            }
        }
    }))
 })
}
```

Comment: I see someone downvoted the question. I obviously can't say for sure why, but it might have been partially because it's a bit of a game of "spot the difference." For your next question(s), when doing something like this, it's best to point out the parts that are different to help people find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key difference is that the first solution is not assuming that the responses will come back in the same order as the requests were made, but the second solution *is* making that assumption. That's a dangerous assumption to make, so it's reasonable to consider the first solution correct but the second one incorrect.

That said, the `currentIndex` variable is completely pointless in the first solution, `i` could be used (since it's declared with `let` inside the `for`).

Here's a slightly simplified example showing the difference:

```js
// A utility function to stand in for the asynchronous part
function doAsyncThing(index, callback) {
    // Take 800ms to respond to index === 1,
    // but only 200ms for any other
    setTimeout(callback, index === 1 ? 800 : 200, `response ${index}`);
}

// The first solution slightly simplified with various
// missing semicolons added
function firstSolution() {
    let count = 0;
    const message = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        let currentIndex = i;
        doAsyncThing(i, result => {
            message[currentIndex] = result;
            ++count;
            if(count === 3) {
                for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    console.log(message[i]);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

// The above but using `count` instead of `currentIndex`
function secondSolution() {
    let count = 0;
    const message = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        doAsyncThing(i, result => {
            message[count] = result;
            ++count;
            if(count === 3) {
                for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    console.log(message[i]);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

console.log("First solution:");
firstSolution();
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Second solution:");
    secondSolution();
}, 1000);
```

The output for the first solution has the results in order:

```
First solution:
response 0
response 1
response 2
```

...but not so the second solution:

```
Second solution:
response 0
response 2 <−−−−−−−−−−− Out of order
response 1 <−−−−−−−−−−− Out of order
```

And just for completeness, here's the first solution without the unnecessary `currentIndex` variable (though I think I'd probably change the name of the loop counter from `i` to `currentIndex` or something, since there's another `i` elsewhere):

```js
// A utility function to stand in for the asynchronous part
function doAsyncThing(index, callback) {
    // Take 800ms to respond to index === 1,
    // but only 200ms for any other
    setTimeout(callback, index === 1 ? 800 : 200, `response ${index}`);
}

// The first solution slightly simplified with various
// missing semicolons added
function firstSolution() {
    let count = 0;
    const message = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        doAsyncThing(i, result => {
            message[i] = result;
            ++count;
            if(count === 3) {
                for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    console.log(message[i]);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

firstSolution();
```